# Where do you configure Eclipse Java compiler (javac) flags?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, javac

Ex.

```
javac -g ButtMonkey.java
```

Where do you configure the -g flag when Eclipse compiles Java source? (Using Ganymede but I doubt that has changed in later versions so any answer probably helps.)

What I need is:

> -g
>
> Generate all debugging information, including local variables. By default, only line number and source file information is generated.

Comment: +1 for **ButtMonkey**

Comment: Was hoping someone would get a kick out of that. lol

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Select the menu: Window > Preferences > Java > Compiler

There you will find several check boxes under the heading "Classfile Generation".

Comment: Oh sneaky, they hide the actual flags from you. Was afraid I was going to have to create a custom builder!

Comment: @Mifune Note that Eclipse uses its own built-in Java compiler (which is not exactly the same as `javac` from the JDK), so there isn't one checkbox which exactly matches what `-g` on `javac` does.

Answer (score 0):

For Eclipse version Photon Release (4.8.0)(Build id: 20180619-1200),
Enabling (or disabling) the debug flag in Eclipse IDE,

1. Window > Preferences > (left option) Java > Compiler
2. (section) 'Classfile Generation'
3. (checkbox) '**Add variable attributes to generated class files (used by the debugger)**' // Checking this checkbox will enabled the debug
   flag. Unchecking this checkbox will disable it.

From, Sharma, J; Sarin, Ashish. Getting started with Spring Framework: Third Edition (Kindle Locations 2500-2508). UNKNOWN. Kindle Edition.