# Java Applet work only on my computer?

Tags: java, applet, java-web-start

I'm developing a Java applet that show a message box when you visit the site.
This is my Java code:

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class JavaRun extends Applet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L; 
    public void init()
    { 
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "hello world!");     
    }
}
```

This is the html:

```
<applet width='100' height='100' code='JavaRun' archive='data.jar'>
</applet>
```

On my computer (that have the java SDK) it's work, but when I'm using it on my laptop that have only the standard Java, I get these errors:

```
at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadCode(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.createApplet(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Exception: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Micro : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0...
enter code here
```

Comment: Don't use a mixture of Swing and AWT components, and don't use AWT components in this millennium.  Change `extends Applet` to `extends JApplet`.

Answer (score 5):

I believe You have different versions of Java environments on your computers.
Run this command on both computers

```
java -version
```

And compare version numbers. Probably should run

```
javac -version
```

on Your development machine.
If you get different version numbers update Java runtime environment on your laptop.

Comment: Thank you! in my development machine it 1.7 and in my laptop is 1.6 now how do change this on my development machine?

Comment: Check Mat's answer about -target flag. In short you have to specify in your project settings the target JVM version. Like this:
`javac -target 1.6 -source 1.6 MyApplet.java`

Comment: If you use Eclipse check this SO question: [Where do you configure Eclipse Java compiler (javac) flags?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9483315/where-do-you-configure-eclipse-java-compiler-javac-flags)

Answer (score 4):

> UnsupportedClassVersionError: Micro : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0

This is the problem. You've compiled your applet with a class version that is not supported by the JVM you're running on the other system.

Use the `-target` flags for `javac` to produce class files for a given target JVM version.

Answer (score 3):

```
UnsupportedClassVersionError
```

- To compile code for a particular Java version, use the [cross-compilation options](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html#crosscomp-options).  To do this properly will require an `rt.jar` of the target version (to use the `bootclasspath` option of `javac`).
- To deploy code that requires a particular version, use [deployJava.js](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/deployment_advice.html#deplToolkit)
- To maintain your sanity *and* provide a better user experience, convert the applet to an application and launch it from a link using [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).