# Why Java Applet working only on my computer, but not on the others?

Tags: java, applet, awt

I just wonder something about java applet with awt. I quite disappointed with this problem and want to throw it away sometimes. Below are my descriptions:

1. I already created one application using java applet with awt controls on my own computer, let's say `computerA` using Window 7 32bit Operating System. To up and running this application, I update java version to the latest one.
2. Application is working fine with `computerA`. However, this application also need to run on the others as well. As my own situation, I run with another computer, let's say `computerB` using Window 7 64bits Operation System. I knew that the application created with `32bits java version`, thus I decided to install this java version on `computerB`. However, when I run the application it can only display interface on browswer, but some of its function did not work.
3. Yet I didn't throw it away, I decided to configure in the last computer, let's say `computerC`. This computer use Window 8 32bits Operating System. I did configure as I did with `computerA` and `computerB`. The result is still exact as `computerB`.
4. I also checked up this solution on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9546359/java-applet-work-only-on-my-computer), but it is not fit my problem.

Here are my questions:

1. What is the exact problem on here?
2. Where does the problem come from?
3. Is it solvable?
4. How can I solve this kind of problem? Any helps?

Update:

2. PostgreSQL Database also install in other local computers as well.
3. I noticed that If I convert my code into eclipse project, it worked fine. No problem at all.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: It would be great if you can share minimal testable code.

Comment: Ok, I add it to the question.

Comment: What the..?  @Braj suggests you post an [MCVE](http://www.stackoverflow/mcve) (Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example) and instead you post a link to a face-book that redirects to a dead drop-box link?  If you have an MCVE, post it direct in the question.  External links go stale (some quicker than others) and most people won't follow them.

Comment: I understood what @Braj meant, but the code difficult to minimize to the understandable one that's why I share it as a whole. By the way, thank for your advice.

Comment: Be sure the [Java Console](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/javaconsole.xml) is configured to show when debugging applets or JWS apps.

Comment: Actually, I only did this in my own computer but others not. Is it also the matter?

Comment: WTF? File System access, JDBC database access, and Jasper Reports in an applet? This probably doesn't work because of all of the things that you are trying to do that Java's security manager shouldn't be allowing you to do in an applet, which is "sandboxed". The question is why it doesn't work on B and C, it's why it does work on A. You should consider making this a desktop application, not an applet. And hard-coding paths to things in the file system probably isn't such a good idea either.

Comment: Yeah, I supposed so. As I showed `Java Console` it told me that I have no permission to access local file system. It related to security manager as you said.