# compile java source file with debug info in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I have a spring mvc project in eclipse which uses maven.
I want to compile the java source code in debug info mode in order to get method parameter names at runtime.

How can I do this ?

Comment: see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9483315/where-do-you-configure-eclipse-java-compiler-javac-flags

Answer (score 1):

`Windows->Preferences->Installed JRE's`. Add JDK(Yes, you have to add JDK) like(C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_34). Set it as default, so that you can see java source code
OR

Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Compiler

Click all check boxes under headline "Classfile Generation".

Answer (score -1):

Run the server in debug mode.add breakpoint in your code.Then navigate it with F6