# Eclipse: Unrecognized option: -g

Tags: java, eclipse, jvm-arguments, jdi

I am trying to start an application in Eclipse with the JVM Option "-g", so that I would be able to view all thread info while debugging using the JDI.

However, on start, Eclipse is giving the following:

```
Unrecognized option: -g:
Could not create the Java virtual machine.
```

The full list of my JVM Options:

```
-g -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=4000
```

Other Info:
I am using mac.

I would very much appreciate assistance to solve this problem, so that I could debug without getting the AbsentInformationException in JDI.

Thank you,

Dean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to compile with the -g option.

For Eclipse configuration, see here: [Where do you configure Eclipse Java compiler (javac) flags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9483315/where-do-you-configure-eclipse-java-compiler-javac-flags)

Comment: Ok, does Eclipse support that? If so, where do I put it?