# couldn't find preferences under window menu option in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I want to add javac compiler argument. I found here that I have to add it under windows -> Preferences -> Java in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9483315/where-do-you-configure-eclipse-java-compiler-javac-flags/9483388#9483388).

In my eclipse somehow I couldn't find the preferences option under window.

Below is the screenshot.

[image]

Below is my eclipse details -

Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.

Version: Photon Release (4.8.0)
Build id: 20180619-1200

Any idea why I don't get the preferences option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are on a Mac, so it will be under the application menu, where it says "Eclipse", or opened with `Cmd+,`, just like any other Mac application.

Answer (score -1):

MacOS appleSign Eclipse -> Settings