# sun.jvmstat.monitor.* is not accessible in Java 11

Tags: java

to get current process pid, my project used library sun.jvmstat.monitor.MonitoredHost in STS4. However, STS4 couldn't link this library and I couldn't compile my spring boot project.

```
import sun.jvmstat.monitor.MonitoredHost;
import sun.jvmstat.monitor.MonitoredVm;
import sun.jvmstat.monitor.MonitoredVmUtil;
import sun.jvmstat.monitor.VmIdentifier;

public class MonitorTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }
}
```

That's all the code I have.

Error :

```
The type sun.jvmstat.monitor.MonitoredHost is not accessible
The type sun.jvmstat.monitor.MonitoredVm is not accessible
The type sun.jvmstat.monitor.MonitoredVmUtil is not accessible
The type sun.jvmstat.monitor.VmIdentifier is not accessible
```

used openJDK version is :

```
java -version
openjdk 11.0.1 2018-10-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.1+13)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.1+13, mixed mode)
```

[STS4 intellisense error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6WxTj.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO, please add exception as part of a question and not as an image. Also please share minimum code sample which SO member can try and help you with.

Comment: Actually, there is no any exception or error. I just import sun.jvmstat.monitor.MonitoredHost; but STS4 can't compile with import sun.jvmstat.monitor.XXX.

Comment: that's what I write code. ;(

Comment: I currently used STS4 https://spring.io/tools

Comment: okay try adding `--add-export=jdk.internal.jvmstat/sun.jvmstat.monitor=ALL-UNNAMED` as compiler options and give a try

Comment: do you mean add your option when I run my executable jar? or add optoin in STS4

Comment: like this `javac --add-exports jdk.internal.jvmstat/sun.jvmstat.monitor=ALL-UNNAMED <your-file>.java`

Comment: to make above changes permanent add above line 
 as shown here https://stackoverflow.com/a/54071487/2987755

Answer (score 2):

1. To Solve in Eclipse/STS3-4 version
   Thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54071487/2987755) post, I am able to do changes in eclipse and STS both.

   1. Go to ***Project > Properties: Java Build Path***, tab ***Libraries***
   2. Select the ***JRE > Is modular*** node and click ***Edit...***
   3. Go to the tab ***Details***
   4. In the *Added exports* section click ***Add...***
   5. Enter the following:

      - *Source module:* **`jdk.internal.jvmstat`**
      - *Package:* **`sun.jvmstat.monitor`**

[image: with compiler error]

[image: without compiler error]

2. To solve in IntelliJ idea

modify a file `.idea/compiler.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project version="4">
  <component name="JavacSettings">
    <option name="ADDITIONAL_OPTIONS_OVERRIDE">
      <module name="demo.main" options="--add-exports=jdk.internal.jvmstat/sun.jvmstat.monitor=ALL-UNNAMED" />
    </option>
  </component>
</project>
```

or

Auto-resolve will prompt for above file modification as

[image: idea]

This will solve the issue with idea ide.

3. If you want it to add to build tools like `maven` or `gradle` then

`javac --add-exports jdk.internal.jvmstat/sun.jvmstat.monitor=ALL-UNNAMED --class-path $dependencies -d $targetFolder $sourceFiles`