# Java 8 to openJdk 11 com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.* types not accessible

Tags: java

I am migrating my project from java 8 to openJDK 11. In my code I use the classes

```
import com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.dtm.DTM;
import com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.dtm.DTMManager;
import com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.dtm.ref.sax2dtm.SAX2DTM;
import com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.utils.XMLStringFactory;
import com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.objects.XMLStringFactoryImpl
```

I am using eclipse. I am getting the error that the types are not accessible. I also tried this post with the last import [How to tell eclipse to add-exports when compiling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54068992/how-to-tell-eclipse-to-add-exports-when-compiling/54071487#54071487)

But it did not work. Any idea how could we fix this? Does the error mean that the packages have become internal and should be replaced in the code?

Comment: This is exactly why you are advised against using vendor specific classes explicitly because they can change or go away without warning.  Bring in your own copy of the library.

Comment: What do you mean by "Bring in your own copy of the library"?

Comment: `com.sun.org.apache.xml` is how Sun imported existing third-part libraries in the Java runtime.  Change their package so it didn't clash with a user-provided `org.apache.xml` package (most likely Xerces).  Remove these imports, bring in a suitable version of Xerces, and let your IDE help reimporting.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue where I needed to update a reference to `com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serializer.OutputPropertiesFactory`, and found I could change it to:

```
import org.apache.xml.serializer.OutputPropertiesFactory;
```

if I included the right Xalan apache xml dependency:

```xml
    <dependency>
        <groupId>xalan</groupId>
        <artifactId>xalan</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: @Lore You can be notified of changes to a post by following it (Follow button).

Answer (score 1):

In openJdk11 you have to import xml-security.jar ( com.sun.org.apache.xml is not present so you have to)

Answer (score 0):

Trying this solved my problem:
**import java.net.URI;**

I had the same issue while trying

```
URI location = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequest().path("/{id}").
                buildAndExpand(savedUser.getId()).toUri();
```

in JDK 11. When I tried the recommended imports(**`import com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.URI, import com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.utils.URI`**). I got the same error.