# Eclipse cannot find JavaFX 11 Legend type

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx

I'm trying to get some java 1.8 code working in Java 11.  I've hit what seems to be a common wall, but none of the answers I've found are working.

System: Fedora 33 5.9.8-200.fc33.x86_64 
Eclipse Version: 2020-09 (4.17.0) Build id: 20200910-1200 
JDK: java-11-openjdk-11.0.9.11-0.fc33.x86_64 
JavaFX: OpenFX javafx-sdk-11.0.2

Here's the bit of code that's blocking me.

```
class MyPie extends PieChart {
   public Legend legend;
   
   public MyPie() {
      super();
      legend = (Legend) getLegend();
   }
}
```

The error is: "Legend cannot be resolved to a type"  When I ask Eclipse to auto-generate an import statement, or use the suggestion, it put in this line:

```
import com.sun.javafx.charts.Legend;
```

This is a problem, because that doesn't seem to exist and doesn't follow the same pattern as the other JavaFX imports:

```
import javafx.scene.chart.PieChart;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
```

I have a second one "com.sun.javafx.css.StyleManager" which I'm guessing will have the same solution.

What am I missing here?

Thanks.

Comment: `com.sun` packages and classes are not part of the public API and are not guaranteed to be available in future releases. You use them explicitly assuming the risk this may happen.

Comment: If you **must** use private API then you'll need to use `--add-exports` and/or `--add-opens` to grant your module (or all unnamed modules) access. These command line options must be specified at compile-time _and_ run-time.

Comment: @James_D I guess that's really my question...  Were these deprecated in OpenFX between 8 and 11?  Did the name change?  I can't find any information about these, or how to replace them with something public.   

Slaw: Where do I do that in Eclipse?

Comment: Neither of those: the class [still exists in the current version](https://github.com/openjdk/jfx/blob/master/modules/javafx.controls/src/main/java/com/sun/javafx/charts/Legend.java). You can't access it because of the new module system in Java 9 and later, which is *designed to prevent you from using non-public API*. You can work around it as described in @Slaw's comment. (I believe you need something like `--add-exports=javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.charts=ALL-UNNAMED` to both the compiler and JVM)

Comment: I'm still floundering here.  If they've been made private and might be removed in future released, are there not public replacement for them?

I think I've sort of found where to put that in, but it's still not right. 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54068992/how-to-tell-eclipse-to-add-exports-when-compiling/54071487 refers to a deprecated dialog box.  When I go to the new version, I see that com.sun.javafx.css is in javafx.graphics.  That seems to have worked.  However, com.sun.javafx.charts isn't showing up as being in javafx.controls (or any of the other javafx libraries).

Comment: And I just searched for `Legend` and it's definitely in the `com.sun.javafx.charts` package which is in the `javafx.controls` module (at least in JavaFX 15). "_If they've been made private and might be removed in future released, are there not public replacement for them?_" – they were **always** private, the module system just makes this explicit; there can't be a replacement because there's nothing to replace.

Comment: I've managed to add "--add-exports javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.charts=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.css=ALL-UNNAMED" but now all I get is "WARNING: Unknown module: javafx.graphics specified to --add-exports
WARNING: Unknown module: javafx.controls specified to --add-exports" when I run.

Comment: That sounds like you aren't putting JavaFX on the module-path, but rather the class-path. If you haven't already, check out [Getting Started with JavaFX](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/) to see how to properly setup JavaFX in Eclipse.

Comment: I thought that might have been the case as well, but Eclipse is telling me that this is being put on the command line "-p /home/Greg/src/jfx/javafx-sdk-11.0.2/lib/javafx.base.jar:/home/Greg/src/jfx/javafx-sdk-11.0.2/lib/javafx.controls.jar:..."  It's also not helpful that that link talks about using Java 15, when Eclipse 2020-09 doesn't actually support it as an environment...

Comment: OK.  I also had to mysteriously add a module import statement for javafx.web, even though it's in the list of modules to be loaded.

"--module-path /home/Greg/jfx/javafx-sdk-11.0.2 --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.graphics --add-exports javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.charts=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.css=ALL-UNNAMED --add-modules javafx.web" seems to be doing the trick.